# Writing scala enum into database and reading from it

Tags: json, scala, enums, playframework-2.0

I've been working with some legacy code and I've some troubles.
I have enum written by other guy and now I should write into database some data and read from it. Here some examples:

Here's the enum

```
object MarketType extends scala.Enumeration {
  type MarketType = Value
  val Continent, Country, State, City = Value
  implicit val marketTypeReads = EnumUtility.enumFormat(MarketType)
}

case class Market(
  id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
  name: String,
  marketType: Option[MarketType] = None,
)

object Market {
  val writes = new Writes[Market] {
    def writes(o: Market) = Json.obj(
      "id" -> o.id,
      "name" -> o.name,
      "type" -> o.marketType
)
}

 val reads: Reads[Market] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[ObjectId].map(validateAndFetchObjectId) and
      (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "type").read[MarketType]
)(Market.apply _)


implicit val format: Format[Market] = Format(reads, writes)
```

Here's JSON which I take from front-end and what I should write to the database :

```
{"name":"Name","type":"state","description":"Desc"}
```

Comment: You don't mention what the trouble you are having is. Can't find it from the code since the EnumUtility class seems to be internal to your code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about it. I have troubles when I try to write my json from front-end part into database because I can't parse json 'type' to the enum. Without this 'type' my class working fine. Same as read.

Comment: Still, there is not enough information to answer the question properly.

Comment: I dunno how I can describe this more clearly because there're my JSON which I get from my front-end, There're my object which should be saved into database, for example `{name: "myName"}` json can be saved into database as a String, but `{type: "type": City}` cannot be saved into database as a enum of MarketType. There my question, which way should I go to write\read these data.

Answer (score 0):

**Change this**:

```
val reads: Reads[Market] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[ObjectId].map(validateAndFetchObjectId) and
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "type").read[MarketType]
)(Market.apply _)
```

**Into this**:

```
val reads: Reads[Market] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").readNullable[ObjectId].map(validateAndFetchObjectId) and
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "type").read[MarketType]
)((id, name, type) => Market(id, name, Some(MarketType.withName(type))))
```

**Things to watch out for**:

The JSON you posted has the value of the `type` field in lower case; this will throw a NoSuchElement exception in production when passed into the `MarketType.withName()` method. Ensure the clients of your API send this field in Camel case

Example: `{ .., type: "State", .. }`